height: calc(100vh - 76px); does not work properly
My left menu does not fill the entire page when other elements make it longer. Normally it works fine:
when site is full size

. But when i make it smaller there appears a blank:
smaller site, theres a blank below

width: 180px;
height: calc(100vh - 76px);
z-index: 700;
background-color: white;
padding: 20px 0;

display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;

Theres "-76px" becasue of navbar above of this left menu, i tried min-height or 100% instead of 100vh but nothing works. Someone can fix it?

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon. See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Little more context:
.left-menu{
width: 180px;
height: 100%;
z-index: 700;
background-color: white;
padding: 20px 0;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;

a.left-menu-link{
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 14px);
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

}

From your screenshots it's clear that you have a sidebar and a content bar. You have a CSS rule which works properly if the content bar is smaller than the sidebar, but you have an issue when the content bar is greater than your sidebar.
You can solve this problem via several ways, so you can choose the one that suits you best:

you could at page load measure the size of the content bar and if it's larger than the sidebar, then adjust the sidebar's size via Javascript

pro: easy, reliable
con: you use Javascript to fix a glitch


you could make your content bar be of the same height as your sidebar and have a vertical scroll bar

pro: easy, reliable
con: a scrollbar inside your content bar when needed



See the example below:


.sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.content {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.sidebar, .content {
    height: calc(100% - 76px);
}

body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="content">
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
<p>sdjfskljdfhsdlkjfhskfjhsdjfshsjkdfhsjkfhksdhfsjkhfskjfdsh</p>
</div>




its not my own project so i propably cant do this your way, whole site should be scrollable, and about javascript im not sure, im not that advanced, but thanks for your help, maybe you can help me adjust solution above?

@newbie123 can you specify what exactly can't you do? Do you have access to the source code and can you make changes upon it?

i can but whole site should be scrollable, thats what i meant

@newbie123 can you explain what is exactly not scrollable that should be scrollable? Is it the sidebar? Do you want to scroll the sidebar?

in your example sidebar is still, while content only scrolls, my whole page with navbar sidebar and content should scroll as one, idk if im making it clear enough

@newbie123 can you create a fiddle with your problem? I will not create another fiddle from scratch.

so i guess u are trying to make a sidebar, that way you can make the position property to be fixed. you can add this codes below:
position: fixed;
top:0;
bottom:0;

then readjust your codes so that other elements start after the sidebar.
for proper clarity, please provide more code

kinda works, but it overlaps my navbar, and when i set - top:[navbar size]px - its has this margin permanently while scrolling, can i make this margin but "stick it" to navbar somehow?

give the navbar a greater z-index, so the sidebar is behind, then u can adjust the padding-top of the sidebar to start exactly below the height of the navbar.

alternatively, u can adjust the 'top' property to the start below the navbar. for example, if the navbar's height is 100px, the top property of the sidebar should be set to 100px but genarally, giving the navbar a greater z-index should do the trick

its again kinda ok, but due to position: fixed, while scrolling navbar moves away and sidebar leaves blank because of top margin, similar blank as below before

oh yeah, so it's a common convention to use position: fixed property for both sidebars and navbars. that way they both stay at the same position while scrolling through.. you can the readajust other parts of your web page to start below the navbar and after the sidebar

i made a little example on codepen for you, have a look at it here https://codepen.io/biggbhen/pen/QWPmWyw
